# How can I resolve the 'Unexpected input size' error when using MATLAB's trainNetwork function to train a CNN model?

Tags: matlab, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN model with MATLAB, but I keep encountering the same error:

Error using trainNetwork: Unexpected input size. All observations must have the same channel and spatial dimension sizes.

Error in cnn_code_images_resized (line 78): [net, info] = trainNetwork(imdsTrain, layers, options);

However, I have already verified that the channel and spatial dimensions of the images are all equal.
What could be the error?

However, I have already verified that the channel and spatial dimensions of the images are all equal.
What could be the error?